# How to create Space between the td and align the contents inside the td

Tags: html, css

I'm recently into web development and i am facing some issues with my htmland alignment . I have went through various websites & tried using align="left"/right/center but i couldn't just align them.Please guide me  on how to progress .

This is what iam trying to create [image: The Page i need]

This is what i have end up with . Please Guide me [image]

This is the Code i have done . Sorry if i had made any basic mistakes. You learn by making mistakes. I have added My CSS but i dont know why its not getting updated in the snippet.

```css
.boxUp {
 background-color: #dedacf;
 border-color: #dedacf #dedacf #dedacf #dedacf;
 border-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
 <tr>
  <td class="boxup">
   <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
     <td align="right" style="width: 25%">dropdown:</td>
     <td align="left" style="width: 25%">
     <select name="dropdown" class="pulldown1" id="dropdown">
     <option value="Dubai">Dubai</option>
     <option value="Domestic 2">Arabia</option>
     <td align="right" style="width: 25%">textbox:</td>
     <td style="width: 25%"><input name="textbox" type="text"
      size="3" maxlength="3" class="tType1" value=""></td>
    </tr>
   </table>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

Comment: Look like you just want some spacing between 'td' elements. You can use cell-spacing attribute in 'table' tag or simply give some CSS padding for 'td' elements. It will look like some spacing between cells.

like td{
 padding:5px;
}

Comment: What you need?.  Border? , padding?

Comment: I tried Cell Spacing and border , tried padding too .It is not getting  algined.Can i have some basic example where i could refer and work on

Comment: add a jsFiddle of your case, and we can play with it until we achieve the result you are after...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Sure I will try to add my Snippet and code.

Comment: Have Added my snippet.But my css is not getting applied here

Answer (score 0):

OP's table has a table within it's cell, that alone will make layout difficult. The select element needed a closing tag and it's containing `<td>` did as well. Added `border-spacing:5px` to both tables and added black borders for tables and red dashed borders for `<td>`.

See Snippet 2 for corrected version.

This is the only CSS you need:

```
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Adjust the `border-spacing` property to whatever you want in px, em, et. The following Snippet demonstrates the property. You can adjust the table's `border-spacing` on the fly.

#### SNIPPET 1

```js
var in1 = document.getElementById('in1');

in1.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  var x = document.getElementById('tableX');
  var num = parseInt(this.value, 10);
  x.style.borderSpacing = num + "px";
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <title>TABLE</title>

  <style>
    table.x {
      position: relative;
      padding: 0;
      box-shadow: 0 1px 9px 1px #ccc;
      border-radius: 6px;
      margin: 20px auto;
      table-layout: fixed;
      width: 90%;
      height: 100%;
    }
    .x th {
      color: #FFF;
      background: #2C7EDB;
      padding: 10px;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    .x tr:nth-child(odd) {
      background-color: #333;
      color: #FFF;
    }
    .x tr:nth-child(even) {
      background-color: #D3E9FF;
      color: #333;
    }
    .x td {
      border-style: solid;
      border-width: 1px;
      border-color: #264D73;
      padding: 5px;
      text-align: left;
      vertical-align: top;
      position: relative;
    }
    .x thead th:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    }
    .x thead th:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    .x tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 6px;
    }
    .x tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    .x tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
      border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    }
    .x tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
      border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    }
    .x thead + tbody tr:first-child td:first-child {
      border-top-left-radius: 0;
    }
    .x thead + tbody tr:first-child td:last-child {
      border-top-right-radius: 0;
    }
    input {
      width: 6ex;
    }
    /* THIS IS THE ONLY CSS YOU NEED */
    table {
      border-spacing: 0;
      border-collapse: separate;
      }
  </style>
</head>


<body>
  <section id="ii">
    <header>
      <label>Border-Spacing:
        <input id='in1' type='number' min='0' max='15' value='0'>
      </label>
    </header>
    <table id="tableX" class="x" width='90%'>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th id="h0">Header: 0</th>
          <th id="h1">Header: 1</th>
          <th id="h2">Header: 2</th>
          <th id="h3">Header: 3</th>
          <th id="h4">Header: 4</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr id="r0">
          <td id="c0r0" class="cell">Cell: 0,0</td>
          <td id="c0r1" class="cell">Cell: 0,1</td>
          <td id="c0r2" class="cell">Cell: 0,2</td>
          <td id="c0r3" class="cell">Cell: 0,3</td>
          <td id="c0r4" class="cell">Cell: 0,4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="r1">
          <td id="c1r0" class="cell">Cell: 1,0</td>
          <td id="c1r1" class="cell">Cell: 1,1</td>
          <td id="c1r2" class="cell">Cell: 1,2</td>
          <td id="c1r3" class="cell">Cell: 1,3</td>
          <td id="c1r4" class="cell">Cell: 1,4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="r2">
          <td id="c2r0" class="cell">Cell: 2,0</td>
          <td id="c2r1" class="cell">Cell: 2,1</td>
          <td id="c2r2" class="cell">Cell: 2,2</td>
          <td id="c2r3" class="cell">Cell: 2,3</td>
          <td id="c2r4" class="cell">Cell: 2,4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="r3">
          <td id="c3r0" class="cell">Cell: 3,0</td>
          <td id="c3r1" class="cell">Cell: 3,1</td>
          <td id="c3r2" class="cell">Cell: 3,2</td>
          <td id="c3r3" class="cell">Cell: 3,3</td>
          <td id="c3r4" class="cell">Cell: 3,4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="r4">
          <td id="c4r0" class="cell">Cell: 4,0</td>
          <td id="c4r1" class="cell">Cell: 4,1</td>
          <td id="c4r2" class="cell">Cell: 4,2</td>
          <td id="c4r3" class="cell">Cell: 4,3</td>
          <td id="c4r4" class="cell">Cell: 4,4</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

#### SNIPPET 2

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td {
  border: 3px dashed red;
}
.boxUp {
  background-color: #dedacf;
  border-color: #dedacf #dedacf #dedacf #dedacf;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 5px;
}
```

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td class="boxup">
      <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
          <td align="right" style="width: 25%">dropdown:</td>
          <td align="left" style="width: 25%">
            <select name="dropdown" class="pulldown1" id="dropdown">
              <option value="Dubai">Dubai</option>
              <option value="Domestic 2">Arabia</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td align="right" style="width: 25%">textbox:</td>
          <td style="width: 25%">
            <input name="textbox" type="text" size="3" maxlength="3" class="tType1" value="">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for commeting ! can i add Text boxes dropdowns checkboxes inside those table cells .

Comment: I don't think so, but if you make a customized dropdown you can. I assume when you say dropdowns you mean selects?

Comment: That should be a new question, it's not going to be simple.